# Call row_to_json(row) on any PostgreSQL statement (even statements that don't return a result)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for query to always return the JSON representation from PostgreSQL statement, even if there's no `returning *`. Here's an example:

```
WITH result AS (insert into users("name", age) values('drew', 42))
select row_to_json(row) from result as row;
```

Right now I'm getting:

```
WITH query "result" does not have a RETURNING clause
```

Is there anyway to say `result || {}`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `returning` to get results of insert statement:

```
with result as (
    insert into users("name", age) 
    values('drew', 42)
    returning *
)
select row_to_json(row) 
from result as row;
```

Comment: It's a user define SQL query, so I can't make the assumption that returning will be used

Comment: Insert statement never returns data without `returning`, so you have no alternatives..

Comment: @Matt there is only one way: parse and validate.

Comment: @Matt if you can make the assumption, that this *user defined SQL query* is ANSI SQL (or at least, won't use PostgreSQL specific syntax), then you can append `INSERT`, `UPDATE` & `DELETE` queries with `RETURNING *`. If you cannot make that assumption then you're in trouble, because validating the query syntax is no easy (you could try plpgsql and trapping errors, but that won't be pretty/optimal).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem doesn't have anything to do with your usage of `row_to_json`, but rather trying to embed an `INSERT` statement into a CTE.  The following code ran without problem on my Postgres:

```
WITH result AS (VALUES ('matt', 33), ('drew', 42))
select row_to_json(row) from result as row;
```

which output this:

```
"{"column1":"matt","column2":33}"
"{"column1":"drew","column2":42}"
```

You should either use CTE without `INSERT`, or first make the `INSERT` into your `users` table and then create the CTE afterwards.